# Sound capture with multiple microphones?

Tags: ros, multiple

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS-Hydro and I have two audio-technica AT2020 USB microphones that I eventually plan on using for sound localization. However, to start off, I'm testing them with `audio_capture` and `audio_play`, which I got from following [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/audio_common/Tutorials/Streaming%20audio).

The mics work fine independently (I just change the default microphone on System Settings > Audio) but is there a way to capture sound from both microphones simultaneously from two independent channels (so that, let's say, I could mute one but not the other)?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213443/sound-capture-with-multiple-microphones?/) by [Fancyvase](https://answers.ros.org/users/22908/fancyvase/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-07-10

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-07-10**:
audio_capture cannot do this

**Comment by [Fancyvase](https://answers.ros.org/users/22908/fancyvase/) on 2015-07-10**:
Do you know of another package that could do this?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-07-10**:
I don't do a lot of audio work, so I'm not aware of any other packages that might work. (If I did, I would have suggested them in my first comment)

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-07-15**:
'Capture audio from multiple microphones' issue: https://github.com/ros-drivers/audio_common/issues/70

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A set of quick google searches for "ros microphone array" and "ros multiple microphones" turns up:

- https://github.com/introlab/introlab-ros-pkg/tree/master/manyears_ros
- http://wiki.ros.org/roar
- http://www.hark.jp/wiki.cgi?page=MainPage#p2

All of these look like they're doing custom audio capture using ALSA or another OS-level API.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a fork that can at least launch different instances of audio_capture with different devices:

https://github.com/lucasw/audio_common/tree/alsasrc_device

It isn't fully working (for some reason device:="" works when device:="hw:1" does not in my test setup, when they ought to be the same), maybe with a little more work it could be pr worthy.

My setup has a device 1 which is my laptop mic, and 2 which is a webcam mic, so I can launch all these in separate terminals:

```
roslaunch audio_capture capture.launch device:="" ns:="t1"
roslaunch audio_capture capture.launch device:="hw:2" ns:="t2"
roslaunch audio_play play.launch ns:=t1
roslaunch audio_play play.launch ns:=t2
```

I imagine it isn't suitable for localization because the audio isn't timestamped, and the two different streams are captured in different processes.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-07-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1